# How do I get the displacement vector from one object to another?

Tags: quaternion

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have two objects A and B, each in the form of geometry_msgs/PoseStamped.
I would like to calculate the displacement (translation & rotation) vector that I can apply to any (similar) object A' and arrive to a (similar) object B' (respectively).

1. I guess the vector should also be of the form PoseStamped.
2. For translation, can I simply take B.PoseStamped.position.x - A.PoseStamped.position.x (similar for y,z)?
3. For the quaternion, I am not sure if I can simply do division (since adding angles in quaternions is done by multiplication?) i.e. B.PoseStamped.quaternion.x/A.PoseStamped.quaternion.x ?

I would like to avoid having to transform the quaternion to euler and back.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/267839/how-do-i-get-the-displacement-vector-from-one-object-to-another?/) by [ysl208](https://answers.ros.org/users/26761/ysl208/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2017-08-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Unfortunately, you cannot do mathematical operations on the `geometry_msgs` message types. They are plain old ROS messages with no overloaded operators. For what you want to do, you'll need to convert the messages to `tf::Pose` types. Once you do that, follow the instructions in [this answer](https://answers.ros.org/question/267134/tf-inverse-of-a-pose/) to calculate displacement.

---

Originally posted by [Ed Venator](https://answers.ros.org/users/2636/ed-venator/) with karma: 1185 on 2017-08-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-08-10**:\

> They are plain old ROS messages [..]

+1 for this :)

That would be a *PORM*.